# Does download speed actually decrease when you download from a far away server, or just delayed?

Tags: networking, internet, download, internet-speed, speedtest

On [speedtest.net](https://speedtest.net), if I test my download speed to my ISP server, I would get my full download speed which is normal. When I test my internet speed to servers that are 1000-2000km away, I would get only 60-70% of my speed.

My question is was my internet speed actually slow in a way that it was throttled due to distance, or it was normally as fast as the full speed i got from my ISP server but only was registered a little late due to latency/ping?

Comment: Look at your local setup. I am over 2000 Km from the other side of the continent and distance does not slow me down as much as the other (2000 Km away) server.

Comment: Latency (caused by distance) can affect maximum available throughput. A good discussion on this subject can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/870177/can-excessive-latency-affect-throughput).

Comment: Your download speed is not impacted by distance by the server.  In the case of Satellite internet while the distance to the satellite itself is a concern it’s actually the latency that’s the biggest problem.  The actual speed is relatively fast, throughput is the next concern.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah my concern was the throughput. Now I understand that neither Bandwidth, nor latency affect each other. To support my theory, I can assume that, for example it will only take like 1 second to reach my full speed (say 200mb) to local server, but would take like 5 seconds to reach my full speed to far away server. The end result is the same, it just the real time effective throughput in 1 second interval that will trick me into thinking the actual speed received from far away server is slow, right?

Comment: @Mathew: No, that's not quite correct -- it's more than just a visual issue. See StarCat's link, as well as search for "bandwidth delay product".

Answer (score 0):

Download speed depends on your ISP, since whatever you download goes through the
network of the ISP.

If the ISP doesn't have a fast internet line to the network that contains your
download target, the download will be slow.

Sometimes you can get faster downloads by going through a VPN, if its connection
with your ISP is fast enough, and you can experiment by choosing VPN servers
in different countries (if the VPN software allows that).